# PrintDocument (PDF) na horizontal VB

Tags: vb.net

Tenho um `printDocument` que faz o meu *PDF* com a folha na vertical(em pé) gostaria de deixar essa folha na horizontal(deitada).

Meu código que utilizo para gerar o *PDF*:

```
Dim ppd As New PrintPreviewDialog
    ppd.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    ppd.Document = PrintDocument1
    ppd.ShowDialog()
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como deixo a folha na horizontal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era esse codigo que faltava

```
PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
```

Agora a folha fica na horizontal